# How to get started with this integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

One of my bucket list of understanding mathematics is this. How do we work with the integration of $$\int e^{x^2} dx$$

?

Not that I don't know the fact that there is no elementary functions that is the integration of this, but I want to know in detail why that is and I also want to know how it is actually dealt in higher level of math.

In what subject of math should I be looking into studying these ?

Comment: As far as I know, this integral is impossible to take. You can approximate it from a to b though. You can see the related integral ([Gaussian Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)): $\int e^{-x^2} dx$.

Comment: See Also: [Integrate e^(x^2)](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=227660)

Comment: @gangqinlaohu It's not "impossible", it just is not an elementary function.

Comment: [Differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) explains why $x \mapsto e^{x^2}$ and similar functions don't have an anti-derivative expressible using $\exp$, $\log$, polynomials, radicals and function composition.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Since I am studying abstract algebra, maybe I will get to Galois theory some day.  But I will remember that. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}dx=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x^2)^n}{n!}dx=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}+C$